# error in `Image` download In `Universal Image Loader`

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using `Universal Image-loader`,but sometime i am getting `error` while loading image.

`"Image can't be decoded http:/***************/assets/images/NorthernMockingbird1.jpg_600x1024"`.

i am not getting any solution please suggest me what to do.

thanks in advance

Comment: Use Picasso Library... I've left UIL for things like that.

Comment: paste your image path in browser and check if image is getting loaded there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error:**

> Image can't be decoded
>   http:/***************/assets/images/NorthernMockingbird1.jpg_600x1024

From Error i can see that image file extension is `.jpg_600x1024` which is not standard image extension so Universal Image Loader is not able to decode Image.

Try to get Image file name with proper extension.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Agree on this you are trying to load an invalid format! Image must ends with a valid extension like JPG,PNG but not with .jpg_600x1024